# Como não deixar duplicar o meu LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle

Segue a minha sql a baixo uso oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    pf.nome        AS servidor,
    m.matricula    AS matricula,
    ca.descricao   AS funcao,
    TO_CHAR(c.dataadmissao, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS admissao,
    LISTAGG(ev.descricao, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
        ORDER BY
            ev.descricao asc
    ) AS gratificacoes,
    LISTAGG(if.valorreferencia
            || '-'
            || if.tipoeventofp, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
        ORDER BY
            if.valorreferencia asc
    ) AS referencias,
    ne.descricao   AS escolaridade
FROM
    pessoafisica               pf
    INNER JOIN matriculafp                m ON m.pessoa_id = pf.id
    INNER JOIN vinculofp                  v ON m.id = v.matriculafp_id
    INNER JOIN fichafinanceirafp          ff ON v.id = ff.vinculofp_id
    INNER JOIN itemfichafinanceirafp      if ON ff.id = if.fichafinanceirafp_id
    INNER JOIN eventofp                   ev ON ev.id = if.eventofp_id
    INNER JOIN folhadepagamento           fp ON ff.folhadepagamento_id = fp.id
    INNER JOIN contratofp                 c ON v.id = c.id
    INNER JOIN cargo                      ca ON c.cargo_id = ca.id
    INNER JOIN lotacaofuncional           lf ON v.id = lf.vinculofp_id
        INNER JOIN unidadeorganizacional      und ON lf.unidadeorganizacional_id = und.id
        INNER JOIN
    hierarquiaorganizacional   horg ON und.id = horg.subordinada_id
    LEFT JOIN nivelescolaridade          ne ON pf.nivelescolaridade_id = ne.id
WHERE
    if.mes = 7
    AND if.ano = 2019
    AND horg.descricao = 'Secretaria Municipal de Educação - SEME'
    AND fp.tipofolhadepagamento = 'NORMAL'
GROUP BY
    pf.nome,
    m.matricula,
    ca.descricao,
    TO_CHAR(c.dataadmissao, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
    ne.descricao
ORDER BY
    servidor
```

Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Olá, não sou especialista, mas o que me parece, é que seus JOINs está provocando isso. Uma orientação, como que eu faria, põem o mínimo de JOIN, pega um desses casos que estão duplicados e consulta ele fazendo um JOIN por vez. Acredito que você, num determinado JOIN, vai encontrar onde se duplica. Aí é análise para solucionar, mas o importante é entender os dados, como estão relacionados antes.

Comment: Grato ajudo demasiado.